# AngularJS setting headers on GET Request

Tags: ajax, angularjs, header

I'm implementing a login authentication and the backend developer wants me to pass along the key value pairs in the header when i make a GET request. I'm new to AngularJS and I think my problem is the format of my header. I'm able to get a status 200 in Advanced Rest client (chrome extension for testing apis) with this format below. That is the raw format of the key value pairs if i put curly brackets around them or quotes or even a comma it throws an error so i'm very certain that should be the correct format.

```
identity: foo
password: bar
```

I've done every format possible to try to replicate it in the above example. So in my Code it goes like this, and i always get an error.

```
 var config = {headers:{'identity': 'foo', 'password':'bar'}};


this.GetUser = function (config) {
    return $http.get($rootScope.endPoint + '/user/email_token)', config);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['identity'] =  'foo';
$http.defaults.headers.common['password'] =  'bar';
```

and call the api without additional properties

```
this.GetUser = function () {
    return $http.get($rootScope.endPoint + '/user/email_token)');
};
```

Comment: you are welcome, I had similar problem few weeks ago :)